# How to catch bulk response with bulk processor?(Java High level rest client)

Tags: java, elasticsearch

I'm new to Elasticsearch Java API. I know that there are 2 ways to operate bulk:

1. construct a bulk request, use client object.
2. construct a bulk processor, add request to it.

I simulated a large batch of mock data(about 1M pieces), and index them into Elasticsearch(5.6.3) with Java high level rest client.

However,if I use bulk request to index a large batch ,

`java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: nullexception`

happens when I use client.bulk() method.

Then I try to use bulk processor, and it works.
Here is the code:

```
RestHighLevelClient client = initESclient();
BulkProcessor bulkProcessor = initES(client);

logger.info("Use bulk request to load data:");
logger.info("start to generate random data...");
String bossMockIndex = customSetting.getMockIndex();
String soapMockType = customSetting.getSoapType();
Long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
Integer batch = customSetting.getMockBatch();
logger.info("Batch:"+batch);
List<IndexRequest> indexRequesList = bossMockDataService.indexRequestGenerator(batch, bossMockIndex, soapMockType);
Long endCreateData = System.currentTimeMillis();
logger.info("Consumption for creating "+batch+" pieces of mock data:"+(endCreateData-start)/1000.0d+"s");

for (IndexRequest indexRequest : indexRequesList) {
    bulkProcessor.add(indexRequest);
}
```

What I wonder is how can I get this bulk response with `BulkProcessor` just like when I use `BulkRequest`.I need to update some data in the batch of data.

Answer (score 0):

```
BulkResponse bulkResponse = bulkProcessor.execute().actionGet();
```